# How can comets have sand dunes without atmospheric erosion?

Tags: astrophysics, solar-system, comets

This article [here](http://www.futuretimeline.net/blog/2014/10/25.htm) talks about dunes visible on comet 67P:

> In August, the European Space Agency (ESA) achieved a major success
>   when its Rosetta probe rendezvoused with comet 67P. The spacecraft has
>   been returning spectacular images of this strange little world,
>   located midway between the orbits of Mars and Jupiter. Among its
>   latest photographs is the image below showing what appear to be dunes
>   like those found on the deserts and beaches of Earth.

[image]

The comet would acquire an extremely thin atmosphere when it is close to sun. But this atmosphere would have very low density and would not produce winds as on earth.

**So how can there be sand and small rocks on 67P?**

Comment: Acretion? Comets, unlike rocky planets, don't have enough energy to melt and refreeze those chunks of rock, so there's no reason for them not to stay as dust.

Comment: @JanDvorak Are you saying that the comet formed from interstellar dust in a cool region of space. Then how is the rest of the comet is solid? If initial stages were very hot and the comet was molten magma (like earth) then the cooled comet should be uniformly solid rock.

Comment: I'm just guessing, sorry. Maybe they accreted some stuff after cooling down?

Comment: As for dust movement, the solar wind should be able to explain that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What mechanism is responsible for the creation of these dunes on Comet 67P/Churyumov-Gerasimenko?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142920/) Not that we have definitive answers there, but it is the same question.